# iterating large pandas DataFrame too slow

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe where I would like to make a new column based on existing columns.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Test1':["100","4242","3454","2","54"]})
test['Test2'] = ""
for i in range(0,len(test)):
    if len(test.iloc[i,0]) == 4:
        test.iloc[i,-1] = test.iloc[i,0][0:1]
    elif len(test.iloc[i,0]) == 3:
        test.iloc[i,-1] = test.iloc[i,0][0]
    elif len(test.iloc[i,0]) < 3:
        test.iloc[i,-1] = 0
    else:
        test.iloc[i,-1] = np.nan
```

This is working for a small dataframe, but when I have a large data set, (10+ million rows), it is taking way too long. How can I make this process faster?

Comment: @André `apply` is just a wrapper to a loop, that won't be more efficient (python loops are actually frequently **more** efficient than `apply`, but much less that vectorial operations)

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.len` method to find the lengths of strings in the `'Test1'` column and then using this information, use `np.select` to assign relevant parts of the strings in `'Test1'` or default values to `'Test2'`.

```
import numpy as np
lengths = test['Test1'].str.len()
test['Test2'] = np.select([lengths == 4, lengths == 3, lengths < 3], [test['Test1'].str[0:1], test['Test1'].str[0], 0], np.nan)
```

Output:

```
  Test1 Test2
0   100     1
1  4242     4
2  3454     3
3     2     0
4    54     0
```

Note that `[0:1]` only returns the first element (same as `[0]`) so maybe you meant `[0:2]` (or something else) otherwise you can save one condition there.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you want to extract the first character of the string if it is at least 3 characters long. (*NB. for a **string**, `[0]` and `[0:1]` yields exactly the same thing*)

Just use a regex with a lookbehind for that.

```
test['Test2'] = test['Test1'].str.extract('^(.)(?=..)').fillna(0)
```

output:

```
  Test1 Test2
0   100     1
1  4242     4
2  3454     3
3     2     0
4    54     0
```

How the regex works:

```
^       # match beginning of string
(.)     # capture one character
(?=..)  # only if it is followed by at least two characters
```